# Does anyone know if the Genymotion ARM Translator is malicious?

Tags: android, genymotion

I use installed the Genymotion android emulator and discovered that you need the Genymotion ARM Translation. Upon scanning it with VirusTotal it returned this scan: https://virustotal.com/en/file/34507f556e1a74f9a1df4793b9c6c9d60cdcd3963eb441902a5636e5b4922842/analysis/1459906729/ with 9 down-votes. My question is: is this actually malicious

Comment: There are those of us who think that everything published by Genymotion is malicious.

Comment: One precision, this is not coming from Genymotion. @323go I'm curious, can you dig in?

Comment: @eyal-lezmy, just look at their horrific privacy policy. You're selling your firstborn.